# Handlebars Block helper similar to #each

Tags: handlebars.js

I need to build a custom Block Helper called "multiple" **that works as #each when the object exists and works as #unless when the object does not exist.**

The template is something like this

```
{{#multiple Data.Products}}
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert Product" value={{Name}}>   
{{/multiple}}
```

So when we have some products, it will render a collections of inputs whose values are the product names, ideal for editting matters.

On the contrary if there is no product available, I'll be shown an empty input where I could create a new product.

My attempt is this one:

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('multiple', function (context, options) {
        var j;
        var ret = "";
        if (context) {
            j = context.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]); 
            }
        } else {
               ret = ret + options.inverse(this); //NOT WORKING
        }

    return ret;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working nice ;)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('multiple', function (context, options) {
if (options.hash.value === context) {
    return options.fn(this)
} else {
    var j;
    var ret = "";
    j = context.length;


    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

});